# Foundation 6 Change Gutter Width with SASS

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm using the grid-xy system and I'm attempting to change the gutter width of Foundation 6 with my settings.scss file but I'm having no luck. My ultimate goal is to have the gutters between my cells to be 20px wide instead of 15px. I tried changing any variable I could think of or find in my research. Below is a list of variables I've tried.

```
$grid-column-gutter: (
      small: 30px,
      medium: 45px,
);
$column-gutter: rem-calc(20);
$gutters: rem-calc(20);
$gutter: rem-calc(20);
$grid-margin-gutters:  rem-calc(20);
```

I know for sure my _settings.scss is working though because I was able to change $global-width and it did have an effect.

Here is the html I'm using

```
<div class="grid-x grid-padding-x grid-container">
    <div class="cell large-4 medium-6 small-12">
        <h2>Test</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="cell large-4 medium-6 small-12">
        <h2>Test 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="cell large-4 medium-6 small-12">
        <h2>Test 3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="cell large-4 medium-6 small-12">
        <h2>Test 4</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="cell large-4 medium-6 small-12">
        <h2>Test 5</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="cell large-4 medium-6 small-12">
        <h2>Test 6</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do you change the default padding width between grid-xy cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't using the right variables

```
$grid-padding-gutters: 40px;
$grid-margin-gutters: 40px;
```

Worked